# The TCP-Socket-Client connecting to a FIX-API-Server always gets a timeout?

Tags: sockets, tcp, fix-protocol

First of all, `tracert` and `ping` to the given FIX-IP connect within 2-5 msec!

But all the tries to connect with

```
     $Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient $IP, $PORT
```

or just

```
    PS>telnet Fix-IP Fix-Port
```

get a time-out.

Is the normal socket ***not*** the right way to connect to a ( PrimeXM-) FIX-Server?

What else can I try?

I have already asked for the log-entries of their firewall for the exact time of my connection - but haven't get any answer yet.

Comment: If a ping/tracert succeeds, but a socket connection fails, then there is likely no TCP server running on the port that you are trying to connect to, assuming the port is not being blocked by a firewall/router.

Comment: @gooly Any progress on below stated steps? If indeed keen on manual testing, you can most probably use `ssh-putty` on win / `sshd` on linux, setup port-forwarding for a `<localhost>:<port>` become ssh-forwarded onto a known `[Fix-IP]:[Fix-Port#]` remote target, connect to service provisioning and finally then `PS> telnet localhost port` to see a few incoming Fix-Protocol-messages ( again, check the Service-Provisioning-Entity **documentation** on ssh-GWY access details )

Answer (score 0):

### **`FIX-Protocol`** service is first of all well documented on the Service-Provisioning-Entity side

If not, that is a red-light warning.

Typical low-performance **`FIX-Protocol`** gateway is behind a fore-standing access-management/crypto-tunnel service-point.

Thus most probably your [**`Fix-IP`**]**:**[**`Fix-Port#`**] is aiming at rather such SSL-Tunnel / Access-Control device, than a **`FIX-Protocol`** Messaging Engine.

### ToDo

Check your Service-Provisioning-Entity **documentation** before getting in touch with their FIX-Protocol Compliance Testing